# How to return value from different cell of table column by foreign key id in Laravel 8.*

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I made view that adds edits data, to database, its table got foreign keys. So for request I need its id. Can i somehow display name of it while under will be ids?

**Im sorry if title is missleading, i dont know how to ask about this properly**

In my controller im using both tables for foreign and master keys

Im doing it using this: (i dont know how its called)

[image]

**Form code**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputState">City</label>
        <select id="inputState" name="city_id" class="form-control">

            <option selected >{{ $data->city_id }}</option>

            @foreach($city as $city)
            <option>{{ $city->id }}</option>
            @endforeach

        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is you're looking for. On edit, you pass the $data and $city properties to blade and on loop you can make selected the option in select element if the condition is checked

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
   <label for="inputState">City</label>
   <select id="inputState" name="city_id" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      @foreach($city as $city)
         <option value="{{ $city->id }}" @if($city->id == $data->city_id) selected @endif>{{ $city->name }}</option>
      @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
```